# Reactjs: How to customize field for multiple email add and edit

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my project, there is a form field to add multiple emails. For that, I am using "react-multi-email" package, by using this package can add and delete email tags but now I want the edit action also. I am a beginner in reactjs so I don't know how to customize or add any extra function to achieve that. Please give me some valuable suggestions to overcome this problem.

index.tsx

```
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { ReactMultiEmail } from "react-multi-email";
import "react-multi-email/style.css";

const styles = {
  fontFamily: "sans-serif",
  width: "500px",
  border: "1px solid #eee",
  background: "#f3f3f3",
  padding: "25px",
  margin: "20px"
};

interface IProps {}
interface IState {
  emails: string[];
}

class App extends React.Component<IProps, IState> {
  state = {
    emails: []
  };

  render() {
    const { emails } = this.state;

    return (
      <div style={styles}>
        <h3>react-multi-email</h3>
        <ReactMultiEmail
          placeholder="Input your Email Address"
          emails={emails}
          onChange={(_emails: string[]) => {
            this.setState({ emails: _emails });
          }}
          getLabel={(
            email: string,
            index: number,
            removeEmail: (index: number) => void
          ) => {
            return (
              <div data-tag key={index}>
                {email}
                <span data-tag-handle onClick={() => removeEmail(index)}>
                  ×
                </span>
              </div>
            );
          }
        }
          
        />
        <br />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: i believe we can't do it with this library.

Comment: current library doesn't have this functionality. there is an open issue on github related to this issue. 
https://github.com/jsdevkr/react-multi-email/issues/24

Comment: is there any way to define a custom function for editing and call that function inside the "ReactMultiEmail"?

Comment: i was just thinking if it is really a good use case ? i mean if you enter a wrong e-mail, you can just delete that particular email and reenter it. because it is going to affect the performance. you have to tweak the code to call a function when you click on a validated email and do two things. remove that particular email from array. make that email editable. meanwhile you have to handle the condition if there some other incomplete email in input box. it is just going to be complicated....

Comment: thinking as a user.. as of me.. it doesn't matter if i have to renter the incorrect email again by deleting it.